# Continue has no effect in for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, continue

I'm a beginner trying to solve this kata:

> In this kata you are required to, given a string, replace every letter
> with its position in the alphabet.
>
> If anything in the text isn't a letter, ignore it and don't return it.
>
> "a" = 1, "b" = 2, etc.

My solution seems to be working until it encounters a whitespace in the given string, then it includes those as an element of the positions array. I know this is probably fixable by just filtering out the whitespaces but I would really like to know why my code isn't working.

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  const alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
  const letters = text.toLowerCase().split('');
  let positions =[];
  for (i=0; i<letters.length; i++){
    if (!(alphabet.includes(letters[i]))){
      continue;
      }
      positions[i]=(alphabet.indexOf(letters[i])+1);          
    }
  return (positions.join(' '));  
}
```

I thought by using continue, it should just skip over the whitespaces within the letters array but the continue keyword seems to not have any effect.
I have tried to look up the correct use of continue and really can't find my mistake.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you just check if letters[i]==' ' and then continue

Comment: look closer what happens to the variable `i` after you `continue`. And what the next `position[i]` would be.

Comment: @GreenChicken There are other non-letters besides spaces.

Comment: There's no need to convert `alphabet` or `text` to arrays. You can index a string with `[i]`, and you can use `includes()` and `indexOf()` with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `continue` command does skip the execution of the following commands in the loop, but the loop counter `i` is still increased. When you use `positions` with indexes, the gap in the indexes that results from that can be seen when using `join`.

Use `push()` to build up the `positions` array instead of indexes to prevent gaps.

```
for (i=0; i<letters.length; i++){
    if (!(alphabet.includes(letters[i]))){
        continue;
    }
    positions.push(alphabet.indexOf(letters[i])+1);          
}
```